# xpath returns null in BizTalk Orchestration

Tags: xpath, biztalk, biztalk-2010, orchestration

I have a message (MsgPortConfig):

```
<NewTable>
  <InternalID>1</InternalID> 
  <InterfaceId>INT079</InterfaceId> 
  <PortName>PortArchiveNewStartersDestination</PortName> 
  <Type>FILE</Type> 
  <Address>file://c:\test\out\archive\destination\NewStarters%MessageID%.txt</Address> 
</NewTable>
```

When I try to access a value via xpath using the following it always returns null.

```
VarXPath = "/*[local-name()='NewTable']/*[local-name()='Address']/text()";
VarDynamicPortFilePath = xpath(MsgPortConfig, VarXPath);
```

I don't know how else I can do this, checking the syntax with an application like [XPathBuilder](http://www.bubasoft.net/Product/XpathBuilder) works fine but not in BizTalk.  what am I missing? thanks.

Comment: It could be the same as this problem: http://www.wadewegner.com/2007/04/biztalk-2006-xpath-expression-gotcha/

Comment: That was absolutely it Tom, thanks, I've been going round & round in circles with that one.

Comment: Is there some explaination as to why this works? I noticed, for example, this isn't needed when assigning values to the message (MsgPortConfig); only when extracting values out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
VarXPath = "string(/*[local-name()='NewTable' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Address' and namespace-uri()=''])";
```

Comment: Thanks Hugh, as Tom above suggested.